# Prefix Routing in asp.net MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I'm using asp.net mvc 4.0 Internet application.
I would like to know if I can route the controller action like a Web API application.
For Example: if my default route is /Home/Index. I want it to be routed like api/Home/Index.

How  can I achieve this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change maproute like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```